# DLM regression with parameter restriction

Tags: multiple-regression, hyperparameter, kalman-filter, state-space-models

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to fit a state space regression model of the form:

$Y_{t} = \beta_{1}Y_{t-1} + (1-\beta_{1})[i^* + \beta_{2}X_{t}] + \epsilon_{1,t}$

$i^* = i^*_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2,t}$

Should I estimate $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$ trough ML imposing that restriction and then run KF to get the $i^*$ latent variable? Is there a best way to proceed?

Comment: Hi: is there an error term in the observation equation ( the equation for $Y_{T}$ ) or is $i^{*}$ the only  stochastic variable ? Since you're estimating $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, then I would think that the first equation would have its own error term also ?

Comment: Yes, i've already corrected. There is an error term in the first equation too.

Comment: so, in that case,  it's a kalman filter setup but the problem is that the observation equation is non-linear. In that case, I think you have to either linearize the first equation (somehow ) or use a KF that deals with non-linear observation equations. I have no experience with non-linear KF's so I shouldn't say more but that's what you have because of the $\beta_1 \times \beta_2$ term.

Comment: @mlofton It is a linear model so the Kalman filter can be used to obtain the likelihood. What is needed is to impose the restriction on the parameters in the optimization (or MCMC).

Comment: @hejseb: so you are saying that you don't run the KF recursions ( don't view as KF )  but instead use optimization or mcmc  ?  if that's the case, I learned something. if not, could you provide slightly more details. thanks.

Comment: @hejseb: I also don't see how it's linear since $\beta_1$ is multiplying $\beta_2$. Clearly the KF recursions will not know that $\beta_1 \times \beta_2$ are two coefficients and not one ?

Comment: @mlofton The model is linear in the variables, but nonlinear in the parameters. You can therefore get the likelihood from the Kalman filter. If you let the equation be $Y_t=\beta_1^*Y_{t-1}+\beta_2^*i_t^*+\beta_3^*X_t+\epsilon_{1,t}$ you can evaluate this likelihood and consequently optimize it under nonlinear restrictions on the parameters.

Comment: @hejseb: right. non-linear in the parameters. So, you are saying that he should use the KF but the recursions should incorporate the parameter restrictions ? If so, I get that and thanks. my experience with the KF is that you construct the prediction error decomposition and optimize that to get the variance estimates of the observation and system equation.  then, once you have those, you run the KF recursions.

Comment: @mlofton I am saying that you set initial values for the parameters, from which you proceed and construct the $\beta_i*$ parameters in my previous comment. Now, given those you evaluate the likelihood. Next, you update the parameters (and consequently also the $\beta_i^*$) using an intelligent move proposed by some optimization algorithm and evaluate the likelihood. Repeat this until convergence.

Comment: gotcha. so nothing to do with KF.  he's got two error terms there so I'm not totally clear how you would build the likelihood  but it's okay. I get the general idea of what you're saying and have bothered you enough. thanks.